# Is it occur memoryleak Using new operator when call a method inside Handler?

Tags: android, handler

when I call method, often `new` operator.
recently I have 1 question.

is there problem when using `new` operator call method inside a handler ?

first please look at the source

```
public clas MainActivity extends Activity {
   private final static int MSG_START = 1000;
   private fian lstatic int INTERVAL = 300000; / 5 MIN

   private recordHandler recordHandler = new recordHandler(this);

   //click record button 
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
        recordHandler.sendEmptyMessage(RECORD_START);
   }

    private static final class recordHandler extends Handler {
           private final WeakReference<MainActivity> weak;

           public recordHandler(MainActivity act) {
                 weak = new WeakReference<>(act);
           }   

           public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
               MainActivity act = weak.get();

               if (act != null) {
                 switch (msg.what) {
                     case RECORD_START:
                        //do record start
                        new MainActivity().startRecord();
                        new MainActivity ().recordHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_START, INTERVAL);
                        break;
                 }
               }
           }
           private static final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {

               }
           };
     }
```

this source , when user clicked record button, start record every 5 minute.

anyway, I want to refactoring to prevent memory leaks.

perhaps, `new` operator is occur memoryleak?

is it problem using new operator when call a method inside handler?

thanks for reading :)

Comment: What makes you think you have a memory leak? What makes you thing the GC won't handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory leak occurs if you place some object in static fields and forget to make it null after using it.

If you are not using static fields, you should not worry about memory leaks. The garage collector frequently looks for unreferenced variables and clean them automatically.

New objects assigned to local variables inside a method are available for garbage collection as soon as the method execution completes. So you are good to go for memory.

But you're using `new MainActivity()`. You should not do that.

If you want to run something in the UI thread, use the method `runOnUiThread` or `anyView.post`

Comment: thanks, you answer `if you are not using static fields, you should not worry about memory leaks`  recordHandler class use static.  but MainActivity not static. so don't worry about memory leak?

Comment: I am talking about static fields, not static classes.

Comment: ah.. `private recordHandler recordHandler = new recordHandler(this);` here?

Comment: Yeah, that is fine. It will be cleaned up when the activity is destroyed.